# _co.send is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Ionic mobile application that uses Typescript and Angular. I am getting the following error:

> _co.send is not a function

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Can someone help me figure out why I am getting this error? I've included my code below.

HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      EMAIL
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding fullscreen="true">
  <div text-center style="margin-top: 5cm">
    <button ion-button (click)="send()">Send-Email</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Angular Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(private emailComposer:EmailComposer ) {}

    send() {
        this.emailComposer.isAvailable().then((available: boolean) => {
            if(available) {
              //Now we know we can send      
            }
        });
    }

    let email = {
        to: 'example@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Cordova Icons',
        body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
        isHtml: true       
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'let' outside of a function, which is unallowed. That may be causing you some issues. Try moving the email definition inside of send(), and just before this.emailComposer.isAvailable().

Also, make sure to add this.emailComposer.open(email) in your 'if' block.

Please show the entire error output so we know this error isn't caused by another.